# How to press enter to click a button without submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I currently have a sign in button that onclick, shows a loading icon for 2 seconds and then shows a hidden div, the hidden div is also part of the form and contains a final submit button that actually submits the form. The sign in button simply shows the hidden div. I would like to be able to press enter on the password section of the form which would press the button, which would then trigger this function which is shown below.

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('SteamLogin').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "block";
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
},2000);
}
```

The username and password input for my form allow me to press enter, however it submits the form, which i do not want. I want the enter key to simply press the sign in button, which shows the hidden div. That's all.

```
<input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="button" 
name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" 
border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv();">
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is to listen to the `submit` even on the form.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // If '#userLogin' is the submit button for the form, just move the
    // code for the `$('#userLogin').click()` event handler in here.
    showDiv();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean press enter while foucs on input tag, and then just show the div which is hidden?

```
$('form input').keypress(function (e) {
  var key = e.which; //e.which is the code of press
  if (key == 13) { // 13 means enter
    alert("enter!");
    //do someting....
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default handler
    e.stopPropagation() //stop propagation of the event
  } 
});
```

if you have not listen the enter press ,maybe it is a default handler of browser
try using  `onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13)return false;"`
add this attr to your form like this:
`<form onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13)return false;">xxxxxxx</form>`

i have made an example for you, the `return false` stoped the default handler:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form onkeydown="showDiv();return false">
    <input type="text"  name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" >
    <input type="password"  name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" >
    <input type="button"  name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" onclick="showDiv();">
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25"  onclick="submit();">
  </form>
 </body>
 <script>
    function showDiv() {
        console.log('show');
    }

    function submit() {
        console.log('submit');
    }
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: YES exactly like what you said, when I use this script pressing enter still submits the form

Comment: I have a form that inside has two buttons. The first button does not submit anything. It just shows a hidden div. When the user is inside the username or password field I would like enter to simply click the button is that possible?

Comment: maybe the example can help you